# Seeking solution for implementing backups in only one DC

Tags: mariadb, galera

We are running MariaDB Galera cluster in 3 Datacenters. We are using mariabackup tool for taking backups in each datacenter but, since the same data is replicating on all the 3 datacenters we are trying to implement a solution which includes executing the backup script in only DC and if there is downtime in the DC which is taking backups the backups should run in other DC automatically. Any solution for this approach is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of "Event & Trigger" to accomplish this.

I use zabbix to monitor my daily mariabackup and I had the problem that the node was down while mariabackup was running.
I don't really care if I lose one day backup since I also have ZFS SNAPSHOT backup.

But if you want to, you can also set some trigger action in zabbix to make the backup script run on another server.

Another solution I would choose would be saltstack 'beacon & reactor'. A beacon can be created to send an event and a reactor can be triggered to take some actions. Since I am running saltstack for all my servers, this would be a solution I prefer.